# What is the relationship between ∅ & ☽?

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-game-theory

In [HACKENBUSH: a window to a new world of math](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYj4NkeGPdM&t=3143s) Owen says that ☽ (loony) is equal to the set of no nimbers (eg. $☽=\{\}$).

**That seems to imply $\emptyset = ☽$. Is that the case? Or is $\emptyset || ☽$?**

Additionally, in the video Owen also says loony is "apparently used for something else too(?)" - but doesn't go on to say what or give any references. **What else is ☽ used for?**

Comment: Division isn't even defined for $*1$; and exponentiation doesn't have a universal meaning for surreal numbers. Do you have  any reason to think these would be defined for ? Also, you ask a whole lot of different questions in this post, when it's supposed to be just one per post so that it's clear what should be answered. Please edit.

Comment: Yes, it's the empty set.

Comment: @MarkS. edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overall meaning

In all uses I am aware of, ☽ represents a position that you would be [loony](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/loony) to move to (typically in a component of a larger game), because you would lose the game, or at least gain no benefit from the move.

The details of this vary a bit depending on the context.

## Types of uses

### Use #1

#### Context

In the second edition of Winning Ways, Chapter 12 "Games Eternal - Games Entailed" has a relevant section called "Entailing Moves", which starts on page 396 (which I found by looking up "loony" in the index). In this section, it is argued that best play under normal play in an impartial game that would be a disjunctive sum with a special rule about "entailing moves" which require a response in the *same* component can be understood by assigning not just a single nimber to each component (as in the [Sprague-Grundy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem)), but rather a *set* of nimbers.

#### Definition

In this context, the empty set of nimbers happens to be what you would assign to a position where moving to it loses the entire game. As such, they define ☽ on page 398 to be the empty set of no nimbers. So here the answer to ☽$\,=\varnothing$ is technically "**yes**".

#### Caveat

However, I want to caution that this empty set is *not* the same "empty set" that you might think of as represented by the nimber $*0$ (or the game $0$ in a partizan/surreal context). The nimber $*0$ when treated as a set is "the set of positions you can move to from the canonical game with Grundy value $0$", which happens to be $\varnothing$.

But 1. other impartial games treated as sets also have the Grundy value $0$ and 2. the sets in the discussion of games with entailing moves (where ☽ arises) are *not* the sets of positions you can move to, nor even the sets of nimbers/Grundy values of positions you can move to (because in this context, positions don't typically have meaningful single Grundy values).

### Use #2

On page 322 in Chapter 10 of the second edition of Winning Ways, there is a table of "tallies" for the game "Baked Alaska", in which they are treating square cakes as illegal positions. They write "we've...written simply ☽ for the illegal square cakes". However, the initial description of Baked Alaska says that a person who sees a square cake may win instantly. This means that you would have to be loony to move to them.

Here, no definition about ☽ being any particular set is made, because there is no need. But it is still like "Use #1" in that a move to ☽ loses the game (and so you would have to be loony to move to ☽ in a component).

Since Owen Maitzen seemed to primarily be using Winning Ways as his source, I suspect this was the "something else" referred to in the video.

### Use #3

In "The Dots and Boxes Game" by Elwyn Berlekamp, he defines a "loony move" (to a "loony position") as one in which a certain general theorem guarantees that the opponent will be able to score at least half of the remaining points in the game. He also uses the ☽ symbol to denote positions that are not worth moving to (probably because they are loony positions in this sense).

Here again, there is no natural set definition for ☽.

## Bonus question

Remaining is the question as to whether $\varnothing\parallel$☽. However, $\varnothing$ is not the way any partizan game is written (so that $\parallel$ is not a symbol that usually applies). And if we are in an impartial context so that $\varnothing$ represents the impartial game with no moves available, then $\parallel$ just means $\ne$, in which case  $\varnothing\ne$☽ is indeed true in the context of Use # 1, and I suppose could depend on the play convention in a more general context.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to understand is related to ☽+0=☽+*1=☽+*2=...=☽+☽=☽. I think this implies ☽ is idempotent & if ☽ = ∅, then ∅ is idempotent as well? Which is just not a way i have ever thought about ∅..

Comment: Also I thought *0=0 not ∅

Comment: Idempotent just means $x+x=x$ or similar. As mentioned at the end of my answer, $\varnothing$ isn't usually a game (do you mean the game $*0$?), and addition of sets of nimbers that represent values of games with entailing moves doesn't work like, say, addition of sets of games for defining the surreal numbers. So basically, there's no standard meaning for $\varnothing+\varnothing$ that applies here.

Comment: Whether $*0$ is $\varnothing$ or $0\cong\{\mid\}$ or neither of those depends on the context.

Comment: I think you thoroughly covered uses. Your explanation also makes sense as to part of my confusion (eg. it seems to really depend on the context - this is the first time I can understand using fuzzy or confused with). I'm going to post a question about idempotents soon since that is the angle I'm more interested in (compared to "loony" moves). Also, I understand ∅ isn't usually a game. I lack the vocabulary to know what to call it. Not a number. Not a game. Is "value" the best word to use?

Comment: @hypersurreal It depends very much what context you're using it in. If you mean a set of moves for an impartial context, then $\emptyset$ would be a game (position) in which there are no moves available. If the context is this one little section of Winning Ways about impartial games with entailing moves where it's ☽, then I guess I would call it the "value". If the context is working with sets of surreal numbers, then it would just be the empty set (of numbers). etc.